# kill: not a pid or valid job spec

Tags: shell, kill, pid

I have created an application that is basically a deamon written in C.   It is stopped and started using a shell script.   Specifically, to stop it, kill is used to send a SIGTERM signal.   The PID of the daemon is stored in a file on the disc in the format:

```
1234\n
```

A user reports that they cannot stop the daemon, the shell script returns the error:

```
kill: `': not a pid or valid job spec
```

The PID is fetched and used in the shell script as follows:

```
if [ -f "${PID_FILE}" ]
then
    FCPID=`head -n 1 $PID_FILE`
    kill -n SIGTERM "${FCPID}"
    RETVAL=$?
    if [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ]
    then
        rm -f ${PID_FILE}
        echo "OK"
    else
        echo "FAIL"
        exit 1
    fi
else
    echo "Wasn't running"
    exit 1
fi
```

It works fine on my machine (Ubuntu 10.04) and so far no one else has reported this problem.   Does anyone recognise the error or is there a mistake in the shell script that could cause problems on some platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error occurs when you pass `kill` an empty arg as a PID, i.e.

```
[me@home]$ kill -n SIGTERM ""
kill: `': not a pid or valid job spec
```

My guess is your script throws up that error when the PID_FILE exists but is empty, hence `${FCPID}` ends up as an empty string.

Check that the start script is actually writing out the PID_FILE correctly on your user's machine.

Answer (score 1):

What is `kill -n`? I think you meant `kill -s`. Also, we can check that `FCPID` is being set.

```
FCPID=`head -n 1 $PID_FILE`
if [ -n "${FCPID}" ] ; then
  kill -s SIGTERM "${FCPID}"
  ... # the rest of what happens after kill
fi
```

Comment: The -n flag allows you to pass a signal number instead of a name, so I think kill -n SIGTERM should be equivalent to kill -s TERM.   Interestingly the -n option is only mentioned in kill --help and not in man kill.   Can anyone clarify on what is most correct/compatible?

Comment: Aha, so the -n option is ksh93.   Bourne shell and C Shell don't appear to have this, so the most compatible would be kill -15 PID

Answer (score 1):

Add the flag -kvx(assuming you are using ksh) in your shebang line like below.

```
#!usr/bin/ksh -kvx
```

After executing the script you could clearly see what is the argument that is getting passed to the kill command.